# Create list intance for all the sites and subistes in a Site Collection - Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, custom-list, site-collection, feature

I created a Visual Studio SharePoint project that has a custom list in it. When I deployed the solution, the list instance is created for only the root site and not for subsites. The feature scope is "Site". **Is there is a way to create list instance for all the sites and subsites in a site collection** using this approach? I understand that this can be done by custom code, but I want to check if its possible by using default options.

Comment: I don't think default option exists, list instance is a single instance and can be created in only one site either root or a subsite. If you need custom code, let me know

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Thanks for the response Arsalan. I created a console application for this requirement. Can you post it as answer so that i can mark it as correct.

Comment: Let's wait for others to jump in and see, maybe I will learn something NEW too :)

Answer (score 2):

The list instance was created on the site on which you activated the feature.

Your list should be in a web-scoped feature. Site-scoped features are for site scoped things like master pages, content types and web parts. They will not cause web-scoped things like lists to become automatically provisioned on subwebs.  This means every subsite you want the list to appear on needs to have the feature activated.

Answer (score 0):

If the Scope is "Site" it creates only at root site level, change it to "Web" and deploy it.

Please deactivate, uninstall and retract completely before you deploy your changes.